# finding the last weekday of the month using later.js

Tags: javascript

I am using later.js and trying to get the last working day of the month.
ref: http://bunkat.github.io/later/

```
var r = later.parse.recur().last().dayOfMonth().onWeekday();
```

It eats up the last day of the month which are weekends.
Example: Ex. May 2014 - last day is 31st and it falls on a saturday. What we need is to get 30th the Friday which is a weekday.

I got this reply from the developer
"You'll need a composite schedule that matches 'last day of the month if it is a weekday, or if it is a weekend use the last Friday of the month'. Check out http://bunkat.github.io/later/time-periods.html#day-of-week-count for information on the day of week count time period which is what you will need to use to find the last Friday of the month."

I could not understand yet.

Comment: `later.parse.text('on the last weekday of May in 2014');` - Does this help? ref: http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#text

Comment: didn't work. 'on the last day of May in 2014' works though but the answer is a weekend day :(